# FFmpeg to create slow motion replays to the end of it's realtime video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm looking for a way to create a slow-motion replay to the end of an existing clip (like 3 to 5 seconds).

**  It needs to play normally once and then immediately replay at 25%-speed -with audio **

I currently do this in After Effects pretty quickly and easily, but ffmpeg would be so much faster for the volume of clips I do this to. I'm planning on taking this a step further and writing a .bat file to automate the process down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Use the (a)split, setpts, atempo, and concat filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex 
    "[0:v]split=2[v0][v1];
     [0:a]asplit=2[a0][a1];
     [v1]setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/0.25[slowv];
     [a1]atempo=0.5,atempo=0.5[slowa];
     [v0][a0][slowv][slowa]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

atempo has a lower limit of 0.5, so it has to be run twice. This will degrade the audio. The rubberband filter may provide better results but your ffmpeg will require to be compiled with `--enable-librubberband`, or pre-process the audio with the standalone `rubberband` tool.

See the [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for additional info on each filter.